# How does one map and collect the object IDs of asynchronously retrieved array data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, mapping

So I have a JSON File with multiple arrays "ID" that I want to extract.

```
[
  {
    "ID": 318,
    "Type": 0,
    "Value": 3,
     },
  {
    "ID": 580,
    "Type": 5,
    "Value": 8,
     },
  {
    "ID": 23,
    "Type": 3,
    "Value": 40,
     },
  {
    "ID": 13,
    "Type": 2,
    "Value": 58,
     },
  {
    "ID": 60,
    "Type": 54,
    "Value": 22,
     },
```

```
function getID(address){
  var url = 'https://data.com/api/v1/users/';
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var result = json[0]['ID']+", "+json[1]['ID']+", "+json[3]['ID'];
  return result;
}
```

I have this code that parses the arrays one by one but I don't know how to get all the "ID" arrays at once. Anyone that can help?

Comment: [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @DiegoDiaz ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Comment: @DiegoDiaz ... From all the provided answers are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

To create the array:

```
var result = json.map(({ ID }) => ID);
```

to return the result as string:

```
return JSON.stringify(result);
```

And if you dont want the brackets:

```
return JSON.stringify(result).slice(1, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP might have a look into the documentation of ...

- the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch),
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s and [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) as well as into ...
- [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ... [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

... and into ...

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),
- [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
/*async */function getFetchedApiData(apiUrl) {
  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json());
}

getFetchedApiData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(data => {
    console.log({ data });
    return data;
  })
  .then(data =>
    data.map(item => item.id)
  )
  .then(idList => {
    console.log({ idList });
    return idList;
  })
  .then(idList => {
    console.log({ concatenatedIds: idList.join(', ') });
    // return idList;
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... or with a slightly different syntax ...

```js
async function getFetchedApiData(apiUrl) {
  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json());
}

(async () => {

  const data = await getFetchedApiData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  const idList = data.map(({ id }) => id);
  const concatenatedIds = idList.join(', ');

  console.log({ data, idList, concatenatedIds });
  
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```